# Garbage collection of Stale/abandoned/disused smart contracts on Ethereum

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

What happens to stale/abandoned/disused smart contracts on the ethereum mainnet/testnets?

Is there some sort of a automatic Garbage collection method such as purge to purge these stale smart contracts? i.e., contracts with no longer active pointers

Comment: hello! its not really a duplicate. wondering if there are methods solidity programmers like myself can do to ensure. Is garbarge collection in the roadmap? metropolis or serenity release?

Comment: Yes, it's not **exactly** a duplicate, but both questions are about the same thing, and it was answered in the other post.